# How to iterate over an array of object and show only the latest value in a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a Card component that takes in data called `tag1,tag2,tag3`. This data is from my database and a sample of it is shown below.

I am trying to iterate over the values labelled temperature and show the latest value from the API under `Temperature`.

But currently it outputs every single one of the temperature readings all together.

So how would I just show a single value which is the latest one?

```
const Cards = ({ tag1, tag2, tag3 }) => {
    console.log(tag1);
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
                <Grid item component={Card}>
                    <CardContent>
                        <Typography color="textPrimary" gutterBottom>
                            Tag 1
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2">
                            Temperature:
                            {tag1.map(tag => tag.temperature)}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2"></Typography>
                        <Typography variant="body2"></Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**tag1: array of objects from API**:

```
tag1:
(261) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]

tag1[0]:
0:
accuracy: "15.455"
eventId: "a7e81ca3-b840-4bb1-b41f-821722da4a5b"
humidity: "50"
latitude: "2.708813"
location: {accuracy: {…}, latitude: {…}, longitude: {…}}
longitude: "102.0083215"
name: "Tag1"
tags: {humidityOffset: {…}, rssi: {…}, dataFormat: {…}, movementCounter: {…}, updateAt: {…}, …}
temperature: "28.26"
time: "2020-10-18T01:46:00+0800"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: How do you determine the latest value ? based on time or array index ?

Comment: It would be the temperature of the last object in the entire list of ```tag1```.

Comment: In this case it would be temperature from tag1[261].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first sort the array in reverse order based on time

```
let sortedTags = array.sort((a,b)=> b.time - a.time);
```

Then show the first element

```
<Typography variant="body2">
       Temperature :  {sortedTags[0].temparature}
</Typography>
```

Comment: I tried this and got the error ```Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {location, accuracy, latitude, longitude, tags, temperature, eventId, humidity, time, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.```

Comment: Forgot to add the .temparature in the object. Edited my answer now see if it works

Comment: Yup it works, sorting it by time would be better for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the temperature of the last item you can do like below

```
<Typography variant="body2">
        Temperature:{tag1[tag1.length-1].temperature}
 </Typography>
```